# How to connect GPIO in micro-controller?

Tags: timer, vhdl, microcontroller, gpio

How to connect 8-bit GPIO "General-Purpose Input/Output" with 3 8-bit timers (Timer0, Timer1, PWM) as multiplexer.
GPIO get the 3 Timers outputs as an input, choose between them. It's output is one of the 3 inputs it had as a multiplexer?

How can I make this connection in design also in VHDL by coding?
What will be the functionality of each pin in GPIO?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: 1.this belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com, and 2. there is insufficient detail - you need to show us some code that you already have.

Comment: No previews code I am working on, Just Timers implementation
this is the design required.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/9so3va0kqdxd89i/Capture(2).PNG

Answer (score 0):

```
*-- Assuming you have logic to produce the mux selects: mux_sel(1 downto 0) :*
C1: PROCESS (timer0, timer1, pwm, mux_sel) IS
BEGIN
 CASE mux_sel IS
  WHEN "00" => gpio_in <= timer0;
  WHEN "01" => gpio_in <= timer1;
  WHEN "10" => gpio_in <= pwm;              
  WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
 END CASE;
END PROCESS C1;


-- Even simpler:

gpio_in <= timer0 WHEN mux_sel = "00" ELSE
           timer1 WHEN mux_Sel = "01" ELSE
           pwm;
```